# I have a Kolmogorov forward equation with $\lambda_x = x\lambda$ and $\mu_x = x\mu$. How can I prove a particular identity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

This is Problem #12b in Hoel, Port, and Stones' stochastic processes book.  I have the forward equation figured out (it's $P'_{xy}(t) = (y-1)\lambda P_{x,y-1}(t) - y(\lambda + \mu)P_{xy}(t) + (y+1)\mu P_{x,y+1}(t)$), but I need to prove that given $$ m_x(t) = E_X(X(t)) = \sum_{y=0}^\infty yP_{xy}(t),$$ we have $$m'_X(t) = (\lambda - \mu)m_X(t)$$ using the forward equation above.

I try multiplying both sides by $y$ and taking $\sum_{y=0}^\infty$ on both sides to start, but even after tons of factoring I haven't been getting anywhere.  Is there an easier way to approach the problem?  If not, what is a good way to start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum\limits_{y=0}^{\infty}yP^{'}_{xy}(t) \\= \sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}y(y-1)\lambda P_{x,y-1}(t) - \sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}y^2(\lambda + \mu)P_{xy}(t) + \sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty} y(y+1)\mu P_{x,y+1}(t) \\= \sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}y(y+1)\lambda P_{xy}(t) - \sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}y^2(\lambda + \mu)P_{xy}(t) + \sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty} y(y-1)\mu P_{xy}(t) \\
=(\lambda - \mu)\sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}yP_{xy}(t)
$$